# Avoid multiple long-running nagios tests being executed concurrently?

Tags: nagios

I have custom nagios tests that may take a while to complete (<1 - 15 minutes).  Sometimes when the test takes a while, Nagios will re-run the test during the next check cycle.  Thus, I can see that several of these tests are running at the same time.

I know I can increase the check cycle time, except the test typically takes about 30 secs, so I don't want to increase the check interval and then not see an error for 15 minutes.

I also considered killing existing processes in my test, but that causes an alert to be generated in nagios (and I dont want tests/results to get out of order).

So, is there a good way to handle this?  I'd like to be able to tell nagios, "dont run this check if the previous one hasn't completed yet."

Answer (score 0):

You can write a file to disk whenever the check starts running(make sure you delete it irrespective of success/failed status).

In case a second check spawns up, you can exit succesfully or with a warning  if the file is still present.

In case you have a unique identifier for the process args , you can also skip the check if the process already shows up in the process table(ps -ef )